# Personnalizing a google maps with a menu

Tags: javascript, maps

Got to make a web portal using php/mysql database and a personalize interface like this websites : http://www.barcelonagomobile.com/en/sites and http://www.recyclecitychicago.com/#

My question is : how to make that and in which technology ?? where can i find tutorials for this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Front-end wise, starting by going through [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) would be your best bet. Documentation now is all new, shiny and a pure joy to use. 
As for the back-end, much will depend on what cms you are using, and how you're going to feed the data for javascript to parse through it (XML/JSON).

I've been working with google maps quite a bit, and I found next to none good general tutorials on google maps. However you can stumble upon a few tutorials once you start googling specific development questions about your app.

[This site](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/) makes some good points. However, keep in mind, that it's pretty outdated and heavily references previous versions of the API. Last update was done way back in 2010.

Comment: Also note that googles documentation looks rest, but there are some devlilish details pertaining to converting lat and lon to pixel coordinates and tying objects to the map. Just read carefully what it says and make no assumptions :)

Comment: you are right. there are some changes. as for the devilish details, would you mind sharing the link?

Comment: No link per se other than our website (in my bio). Implementing custom overlays is a bit of a pain, and container pixel (visible on screen) is radically different than div pixel (entire map surface). So getting items custom positioned near specific lat/LNG pairs requires some diligence and testing; the onDraw method fires at not-expected times occasionally, etc. places autocomplete works awesomely straight forward though!

Comment: Now what i really want to know is what technology to use to make the menus like the barcelona website. That's my main question. Thanks